# Why double clicking a cell in Excel, tabs options get grayed out?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016 when I doubleclick in a cell to select some text, most of the options in the ribbon get grayed out. Why? I want to convert some text into a hyperlink and that option gets grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the features in Excel are applied to the cell as a whole. For your example, a hyperlink cannot be added to individual parts of text in a cell, but has to be applied to the entire contents of it.

The features that cannot be applied to individual substrings in a cell are greyed out to prevent confusion. Mostly only formatting options, such as the font colour, size, bold and italic can be applied to parts of the cell string.

Comment: What I usually do is make a narrow column to one side of the column in question, and make that narrow column all hyperlinks.